# Connecting Skype to Asterisk

Tags: sip, asterisk, skype

I have an Asterisk PBX under development, that I would like to link to a Skype account if possible. The idea is that people would call a particular Skype username, and be redirected to my SIP and through that to Asterisk. Is this doable? I have looked around and saw the Skype for Asterisk driver, but of course that has been discontinued. Are there any other options? I would prefer not to have to go through the regular PSTN telephone network but directly from Skype to Asterisk via SIP. If you have any tips on how to configure my sip.conf to get this working, this would also be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

Skype provides a standard SIP trunking interface to their network via a service called [Skype Connect](http://www.skype.com/intl/en-us/business/skype-connect/). Inbound calls from Skype users and an optional PSTN Online Number are supported, in addition to outbound PTSN dialing.

Here is a guide on how to configure Asterisk (sip.conf and extensions.conf) to connect to the Skype Connect trunks via SIP channels: http://www.remsys.com/blog/skype-connect-to-asterisk

With that SIP trunking offering in place, I doubt that Skype will ever support again native Skype protocol drivers for PBXes.

Answer (score 1):

http://sites.psu.edu/psuvoip/2011/12/09/skype-for-asterisk-using-freeswitch-for-hackers/

Here shows you how to use [FreeSwitch](https://freeswitch.org/) + [mod_skypeopen](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/mod_skypopen) as skype gateway for Asterisk

It's complicated but I think that's the only viable way to get what you want at the moment.